# Customer's PingFederate SSO Appears Nonconformant

Tags: xml, certificate, omniauth, saml, pingfederate

My customer has a ping federate installation and it appears to be producing incompatible authentication response documents. The document is well-formed and does not contain illegal characters.

The big problem is that the document's nodes do not contain "ds:" in the node names. This is unfortunate as my authentication library ([omniauth-saml](https://github.com/PracticallyGreen/omniauth-saml)) looks for ds names exclusively [when validating](https://github.com/PracticallyGreen/omniauth-saml/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/saml/xml_security.rb#L82).

Is the library at fault? Is the Ping Federate SAML document at fault? I have started to patch the matchers to use XPath's "contains" helper but even then the document's digests and certificate do not calculate to the correct values.

1. Is the library at fault?
2. Is the Ping Federate SAML document at fault?
3. Should the Ping Federate document, when canonicalized, still verify?

Here's a sample of their SAML response

```
<samlp:Response Destination="http://a/dest" IssueInstant="2012-07-12T18:21:28.011Z" ID="a.valid.rand.id" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://their/issuer</saml:Issuer>
  <Signature>
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <Reference URI="#vZZQnHjOx1.u8c3uupdxDb_cmRu">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <DigestValue>some_digest_value</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>some_signature_value</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>their_well_formed_x509_cert</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
      <KeyValue>
        <RSAKeyValue>
          <Modulus>a_modulus</Modulus>
          <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
        </RSAKeyValue>
      </KeyValue>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
  </samlp:Status>
  <saml:Assertion Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2012-07-12T18:21:28.058Z" ID="SOME_ID">
    <saml:Issuer>http://their/issuer</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">14096079</saml:NameID>
      <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2012-07-12T18:26:28.058Z" Recipient="http://link/back/to/me"/>
      </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotOnOrAfter="2012-07-12T18:26:28.058Z" NotBefore="2012-07-12T18:16:28.058Z">
      <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>http://an/audience/restriction</saml:Audience>
      </saml:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml:Conditions>
    <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2012-07-12T18:21:28.058Z" SessionIndex="SOME_ID">
      <saml:AuthnContext>
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      </saml:AuthnContext>
    </saml:AuthnStatement>
    <saml:AttributeStatement xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <saml:Attribute NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" Name="uid">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">a_uid</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <!-- removed all the other attributes -->
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
  </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: Can you post the full response?   You have just included a sample - the default namespace could be the dsig one which means no prefix (ds:) is required. I would be very surprised if this is the issue - with over 800 customers and hundreds of interoperable SAML products - PingFederate is most definitely conformant. (Note: I work for Ping)

Comment: Hey Scott, the code block ate my first line. Please take a look now.

Comment: Thanks!  As I expected - see the xmlns attribute on the top level samlp:Response tag - it references the dsig schema as the default namespace. I would suggest you test the interoperability with other tools / SAML partners first to help you debug your issues.

Comment: This omniauth-saml plugin already works with OneLogin but it looks like I'll be integrating Ping compatibility.

Comment: Is there no detailed error from omni-saml?  Again - looks like PingFederate is conformant - it could be a configuration mismatch if anything.

Comment: omniauth-saml fails to validate the Reference digests AND it fails to validate the key. It essentially stops working at his line: https://github.com/PracticallyGreen/omniauth-saml/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/saml/xml_security.rb#L82 . Those XPaths indicate it wants elements with "ds:".

Comment: I think your interpretation of that line of code may not be correct.  I believe it is doing the lookup based on the dsig schema (http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#), not assuming the prefix is "ds".  See http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml_doc/classes/REXML/XPath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making this a more official answer...

I think your interpretation of that line of code may not be correct. I believe it is doing the lookup based on the dsig schema (http://w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#), not assuming the prefix is "ds". See: http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml_doc/classes/REXML/XPath.html

Your issues may have more to do with how your libraries are handling the CanonicalizationMethod (http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#) if the signature validation is failing.

Again - hundreds of "off the shelf" SAML products are interoperable with PingFederate.  I'd be surprised if your issue is the result of something that PingFederate has misinterpreted from the SAML 2.0 spec.